# Self-avoiding random walk on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ getting stuck

Tags: random-walk

Let $W_n$ be a self-avoiding random walk (SAW) on $\mathbb{Z}^2$, starting at the origin. Formally, $W_0=0$ and for $n\ge 0$, $W_{n+1}$ is chosen uniformly from  the neighbours of $W_n$ which were not visited earlier:
$$W_{n+1}\sim U\left(\{u\in\mathbb{Z}^2\mid u\sim W_n,\ \neg\exists0\le m<n:\ u=W_m\}\right)$$
(the inner $\sim$ sign means "neighbour of").

However, for a specific roll and for a specific $n$, it is possible that the set of unvisited neighbours from which $W_{n+1}$ should be chosen uniformly is empty. In that case, we say the walk is *stuck*, and leave it determined as is.

So my question is as follows:

- what is the probability that such a random walk will be stuck?
- if the probability is 1, what is the expectation of the hitting time of being stuck?

Comment: experiments show that it will always get stuck and that the expectation is around 70 steps.

Comment: Experiments you have made, or published ones?

Comment: that I have made.

Comment: @mercio https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.447349?journalCode=jcp